# TweenLite's "ease" not working on Angular 7

Tags: typescript, gsap

I am building an animation background with GSAP's TweenLite. and I am currently implementing it on Angular component. but it always throws an error "Cannot find name 'circ' which is included in TweenLite. How do I fix this issue?

I've already tried GSAP's other platforms but it always throws the same error.

/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import TweenLite from "gsap/TweenLite";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent { 

  ngOnInit() { 

    initAnimation();

    // animation
    function initAnimation() {
        animate();
        for(let i in points) {
            shiftPoint(points[i]);
        }
    }

    function shiftPoint(p) {
        TweenLite.to(p, 1+1*Math.random(), {x:p.originX-50+Math.random()*100,
            y: p.originY-50+Math.random()*100, ease:Circ.easeInOut,
            onComplete: function() {
                shiftPoint(p);
            }});
    }

  }

}
```

please see this link for reference on what the output is expected.

https://hencework.com/theme/pogody/constellation/index.html (the dot & line animation on the right part)

Answer (score 0):

I somehow figured it out.

I've researched online and found that I am importing the gsap wrong.

here is the link: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/13445-using-gsap-with-angular2/

somehow you need to point the module at import area in *.ts component (doesn't need to use import)

It still points that Circ cannot be found but output throws the expected result.

Weird...